# c# Take a string from array and store it to list

Tags: c#, .net

This is the Main program, and I have 2 classes the Deck and the Card. **So what I need is to enables a user to take a card from the deck and put it into a user hand which is the List userHand**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        
        List<Card> userHand = new List<Card>();

        // Where I am suppose to enter this **Card drawnCard = deck1.GetCard();**
      
        Deck deck1 = new Deck();
        for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0,-19}", deck1.GetCard());
            if ((i + 1) % 4 == 0)
                Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

So this is the Card Classes, I simply just declared a ovveride string here.

```
 class Card
{
    private string face;
    private string suit;

    public Card(string cardFace, string cardSuit)
    {
        face = cardFace;
        suit = cardSuit;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return face + " of " + suit;
    }
}
```

Last is the Deck Class, I have here the array for the Faces and suits , I also have here the shuffle method.

```
class Deck
{
    private Card[] deck;
    private int currentCard;
    private const int numberofCards = 52;
    private Random ranNum;

    public Deck()
    {
        string[] faces = { "Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6",
                            "7", "8", "9", "10","Jack", "Queen", "King"};
        string[] suits = { "Clubs", "Hearts", "Spades", "Diamonds" };
        deck = new Card[numberofCards];
        currentCard = 0;
        ranNum = new Random();
        for (int count = 0; count < deck.Length; count++)
            deck[count] = new Card(faces[count % 13], suits[count / 13]);

    }

   public void Shuffle()
    {
        currentCard = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < deck.Length; i++)
        {
            int j = ranNum.Next(numberofCards);
            Card temp = deck[i];
            deck[i] = deck[j];
            deck[j] = temp;
        }

public Card DealCard()
    {
        if (currentCard < deck.Length)
            return deck[currentCard++];
        else
            return null;
    }
    }

}
```

Comment: How is `DealCard()` defined?  You should store the dealt card in a variable in your `for` loop and then `Add()` it to `userHand`, which really should be a `List<Card>`.

Comment: @LanceU.Matthews I already edit the code and define the `DealCard()` , Can you show how its done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will help... I added a method that randomly `GetCard` from the `Deck`then display the `userHand` and the Remaining cards.

```
class Program
{
    private static int userCards = 0;
    private static string[] userhand;
    private static Deck deck1 = new Deck();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string[] faces = { "Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6",
                            "7", "8", "9", "10","Jack", "Queen", "King"};
        for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
        {
            deck1.DealCard();
            Console.WriteLine(deck1.deck[i]);
            if ((i + 1) % 13 == 0)
                Console.WriteLine();
        }
        deck1.Shuffle();
        Console.WriteLine("----------------Shuffle cards----------------");
        for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(deck1.deck[i]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Enter how many cards you want to pick");
        userCards = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        userhand = new string[userCards];

        for (int i = 0; i < userCards; i++)
        {
            GetCard(i);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("----------------User Hand----------------");
        for (int i = 0; i < userhand.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(userhand[i]);
        }
        deck1.Sort();
        Console.WriteLine("--------------Remaining Cards-------------");
        for (int i = 0; i < 52 - userhand.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(deck1.sortedlist[i]);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void GetCard(int i)
    {
        userhand[i] = deck1.deck[0].ToString();
        deck1.deck = deck1.deck.Where((source, index) => index != 0).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Card class will be this...

```
class Card
{
    private string face;
    private string suit;

    public Card(string cardFace, string cardSuit)
    {
        face = cardFace;
        suit = cardSuit;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return face + " of " + suit;
    }
}
```

The deck class..

```
 class Deck
{
    public Card[] deck;
    public List<string> sortedlist;
    private int currentCard;
    private const int numberofCards = 52;
    private Random ranNum;

    public Deck()
    {
        string[] faces = { "Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6",
                            "7", "8", "9", "10","Jack", "Queen", "King"};
        string[] suits = { "Clubs", "Hearts", "Spades", "Diamonds" };
        deck = new Card[numberofCards];
        currentCard = 0;
        ranNum = new Random();
        for (int count = 0; count < deck.Length; count++)
            deck[count] = new Card(faces[count % 13], suits[count / 13]);

    }

    public void Sort()
    {
        sortedlist = deck.Select(i => i.ToString()).ToList();
        sortedlist.Sort();
    }

    public void Shuffle()
    {
        for (int i = deck.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            int j = ranNum.Next(i + 1);
            Object temp = deck[i];
            deck[i] = deck[j];
            deck[j] = (Card)temp;
        }
    }

    public Card DealCard()
    {
        if (currentCard < deck.Length)
            return deck[currentCard++];
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou!!!! This helps my code to create a new again.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `List<string> userHand = new List<string>();` declare it as `List<Card> userHand = new List<Card>();` and then lets redefine deck class like this:

```
class Deck
{
    private Card[] deck;
    private const int nCards = 52;
    private Random rnd;

    public Deck()
    {
        string[] faces = { "Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6",
                            "7", "8", "9", "10","Jack", "Queen", "King"};
        string[] suits = { "Clubs", "Hearts", "Spades", "Diamonds" };
        
        deck = new Card[numberofCards];
        
        rnd = new Random();
        
        for (int count = 0; count < deck.Length; count++)
            deck[count] = new Card(faces[count % 13], suits[count / 13]);

    }
    
    public Card GetCard()
    {
        int i = -1;
        Card selectedCard = null;
        
        while(selectedCard == null)
        {
            i = rnd.Next(deck.Length);
            selectedCard = deck[i];
        }
        
        deck[i] = null;
        return selectedCard;
    }
}
```

And now simply `deck.GetCard()`. You will have problem if deck is empty (everything is dealt) so it will be stuck at `while` loop inside `GetCard()` so you need to check if everything inside array is empty and if so throw exception for empty deck.

Better approach would be to convert array to `List<Card>()` since it would be easier to manipulate for you (have `Count()` and `Remove()` methods)

Comment: I got error at `while(selectedCard = null)` I added extra `=` then no error, My remaining error now is the `deck[i] = null;` the i error says `Use of unassigned local variable "i"`

Comment: Error in `deck[i] = null;` CS0165 Use of Unassigned Local Variable "i"

Comment: My bad. Will edit in few seconds

Comment: @XmPar Check it, it is edited.

Comment: I got error after I run the program , The error it's in the `Exception Thrown` `i = rnd.Next(deck.Length);` The error says `Object reference not set an instance of an object` ..... `rnd was null.`

Comment: Well it should have given you error at line `ranNum = new Random();` since `ranNum` doesn't exist, i declared it as `rnd` so change it to `rnd = new Random()`. Also search google what that error means since it is easy error.

Comment: Thankyou! It displays now no error, but how what code needed for me to able to take a card from the deck?

Comment: You have `GetCard()` function. It returns you drawn `Card` and removes it from that deck. So simply `Card drawnCard = deck.GetCard()`

Comment: And then do whatever you want with `drawnCard` variable.

Comment: Are you there? I need some help.

Comment: I am and I saw your comment which you removed for some reason, but what you are asking is question related on logic not problem. How do I know where you will use your card? I told you with `deck.GetCard()` you get `Card` in return which is then removed from that deck and do whatever you want with that card. I do not know what you want.

Comment: I'm stuck for 4 hours finding for answer in all other platforms.

Comment: Okay this, After printing all the deck of cards, the program will ask me what do i want to take from Deck of cards. Can u show me how is this in code? `Printing the Deck of Cards` then `Program ask : What card do you want to take` last is show the `userHand`